# Symfony 1.4 - Changing Code With FTP

Tags: symfony-1.4

I am currently editing the code of my Symfony 1.4 Website using Sublime Text and pushing it to the web server with an FTP client.

However I have added a new module called 'about' and added the template and actions folders with the relevant files but when i try to go to mysite /about it just redirects me to another page.

I have the Routing.YML setup as follows

```
    homepage:
  url:   /
  param: { module: home, action: index }

  about:
  url:   /about
  param: { module: home, action: about }

stats:
  url:   /footballfans/stats
  param: { module: footballfans, action: stats }

dailytips:
  url:     /dailytips/index
  param:   { module: dailytips, action: index }

footballnews:
  url:     /footballfeed.:sf_format
  param:   { module: footballfans, action: atom, sf_format: atom }
  requirements:
    sf_format: (?:atom)  

default_index:
  url:   /:module
  param: { action: index }

default:
  url:   /:module/:action/*
```

Is there any reason why these changes aren't being pushed to the site? Or do I have to edit a different file as well?

When I edit the template files these changes are being shown in the live site...
When I edit the VIEW.YML file to change the website SEO settings these also aren't being updated...

Comment: Did you clear the cache? If you have ftp only access, you have to use the ftp client to remove the content of `cache/` folder.

Comment: @Marek When I deleted the contents of the Cache folder the site wouldn't load up and just shows a blank page ?

Comment: I think the reason is the cache forlder is not writable by web server process.